# Vue nuxt js updated code refreshes when npm run dev

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

I am new to nuxt js. I have a template of nuxt js which I am working on. In router.js I added some new routes, that's working fine, but when I run my development server again `npm run dev`, the updated code is just removed. I see the old code there. And it only does for the .nuxt folder. Not for the vue components.

Can anyone suggest something? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt uses a method called [File system routing](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing/), with that routes.js file is automatically generated according to your configuration and pages created, that is why your changes get removed

If you have a specific requirement that need more customization you can [extend the router config](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing/#extending-the-router)